# How to create temporary table and generate different name in mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create temp tables which have different table names.

The stored procedure takes no input arguments, create a temp table and return
a table name of the table as T_1, T_2, T_3....

How can I implement this in mysql stored procedure?

Comment: You have something that was tried !!!????

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to get the incremental number in mysql with such requirement. Others things are easy. Does it have something like create sequence in Oracle?

Comment: You mean to say that, on every call to sp, it has to generate a new table name with new suffix number that incremented over the last generated?

Comment: I.e. if this call generates `T_5`, then next call should generate `T_6`?

Comment: Yes! That's what i mean.

Comment: And, do you know that temporary tables are session based. And the tables and session variables are lost when connection is closed?

Comment: I think in Oracle it's not session based, but that does not matter in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following procedure should help you. But this kind of sequence generation will work in current connection session only. But I hope it is OK as you are expecting it on *temporary tables*.

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists set_new_temp_table //

create procedure set_new_temp_table()
begin
  if( @temp_table_seq_num is null ) then 
    set @temp_table_seq_num := 1;
  end if;

  set @temp_table_name := Concat( 'T_', @temp_table_seq_num );

  set @sql := concat( 'create temporary table if not exists '
                      , @temp_table_name 
                      , '( col1 int, col2 varchar(10) )'
                    );

  prepare stmt from @sql;
  execute stmt;
  drop prepare stmt;

  set @temp_table_seq_num := ( cast( @temp_table_seq_num as decimal ) + 1 );
  set @sql := null;
end;
//

delimiter ;

select @temp_table_name; -- should return a NULL before first ever call to SP
call set_new_temp_table(); select @temp_table_name;
```

**Demo** @ [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78eb0/1)

Comment: Does multiple session conflicts when generating tables? How could I change the code as it's not on Temporary table and multiple session can use the same sequence?

Comment: In `MySQL`, variables with `@` prefix are session variables. They only last until connection lives.

Comment: If it is not for `temporary` tables, then you better not use session variables, but define a table that stores an auto_increment value for this specific purpose. Increment it and use it as new table_name_suffix. This would not be conflicting with multiple sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.) To create temporary tables, you must have the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege.

Comment: Appreciate this answer as it's likely the the answer to The Real Question™ for many users finding this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is full example

```
SELECT UUID() INTO @RandomName;
SET @TempTableNameWithSpecialCharectors := CONCAT('TEMP', @RandomName);
SET @TempTableName := REPLACE(@TempTableNameWithSpecialCharectors, '-', '');
SET @tempTable := CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', @TempTableName, ' (InteractionRequestId bigint(20), SendCount int)');

-- SELECT @tempTable;
PREPARE createStmt FROM @tempTable;
EXECUTE createStmt;
DROP PREPARE createStmt;


SET @enqueueDate := '2017-05-28';
SET @insertIntoTable := CONCAT('
INSERT INTO ', @TempTableName, '(InteractionRequestId, SendCount) SELECT InReq.Id, COUNT(*) AS SendCount FROM InteractionRequests AS InReq INNER JOIN InteractionResponses InRes ON InReq.Id = InRes.InteractionRequestId
WHERE InReq.EnqueuedRequest > "', @enqueueDate, 
'" GROUP BY InReq.Id');

SELECT @insertIntoTable;
PREPARE insertStmt FROM @insertIntoTable;
EXECUTE insertStmt;
DROP PREPARE insertStmt;

SET @SelctResult := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @TempTableName);
PREPARE selectStmt FROM @SelctResult;
EXECUTE selectStmt;
DROP PREPARE selectStmt;
```